# Versioning Python extension that builds against upstream library

Tags: python, versioning, setuptools

I am really confused on how to properly combine versioning for my own extension with the versioning of the upstream library I am interfacing to.

### Background in a nutshell

There is an upstream static library (say, version `2_2_0_5`), and I am building a Cython extension named `foobar` to provide an interface to it (say, version `0.5.3`). Because upstream library is huge, I won't be able to cover its interface in a single shot, so I need to version my own extension as well.

Once new version of upstream is released, I take the latest version of my extension for previous version of upstream and start adjusting it according to the changes in the upstream release, increasing my own version number.

### Requirements

I have to provide an easy way to restrict the version of my extension being installed to the given upstream version, something like `pip install foobar[upstream==2.2.0.5]`.

### Options I have considered

#### `foobar-2.2.0.5+0.5.3`

I have considered using local version labels, like `2.2.0.5+0.5.3`, but because local version label has no semantics, I cannot install specific version of my extension without explicitly mentioning the version of upstream — there is seemingly no way to tell `pip` to do something like `pip install foobar>=*+0.5.3`.

#### `foobar-0.5.3+2.2.0.5`

An approach where my version is the "primary version" and upstream version is my local version label suffers from inability to pinpoint exact upstream version.

#### `foobar_2_2_0_5-0.5.3`

Another option I had considered is to inline the upstream version into the name of package itself, so I will have `foobar_2_2_0_5-0.5.3` and `foobar_2_2_1_9-0.6.8`, but this seems extremely ugly to me, and does not offer any filtering capabilities — I cannot install `foobar` for `upstream~=2.2`.

#### `foobar[upstream.2.2.0.5]-0.5.3`

There are "extras" in setuptools, so package can be installed with `foobar[hello,there]`, but there is no way to version extras — they are mere flags. And I am not sure whether having extra like `foobar[upstream.2.2.0.5]` would actually do any help, and readability suffers anyway.

I could theoretically make `foobar` a "virtual package" that would install relevant dependency given correct extra:

```
setup(
    name='foobar',
    extras_require={
        '2.2.0.5': ['foobar_2_2_0_5'],
        '2.2.1.9': ['foobar_2_2_1_9'],
    }
)
```

In practice this would effectively disable the way to specify `foobar` version, and is essentially not different from `foobar-2.2.0.5` approach.

### What next?

I have to also keep in mind that upstream developers may use my extension with private builds, so it's necessary to make it possible to keep build tags in upstream version. I don't know how to accomplish that.

Also, reading [explanations on the purpose](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2014-December/025414.html) of local version labels, it can be clearly seen that my use contradicts the intended use. However, I don't see any other mechanism I could make to use.

Given this all, I am really confused on what to do next, is there a way to solve this without rewriting half of the `setuptools`, and whether I am missing some obvious solution after all.

Comment: Are you saying the upstream library is something installable via pip.setuptools, or something totally external to Python?  Also, at first you say you want to "restrict the version of my extension being installed to the given upstream version", but then you say it's bad that "I cannot install specific version of my extension without explicitly mentioning the version of upstream".  Are you saying you want to be able to both install a specific version of your library *and* install a version that matches the upstream (without knowing which version of your library matches that upstream version)?

Comment: @BrenBarn upstream is a static C library (2GiB worth of .a files), and whole point of my extension is to provide a Python interface to it via Cython extension.

Comment: @BrenBarn As for the requirements ambiguity, yes, you are correct. I want to support these scenarios: "install specific version of my lib, and I don't care what version of upstream would it be" (`foobar==0.5.3`) and "install latest version of my lib that can work with exact upstream version" (`foobar[upstream == 2.2.0.5+sometag]`) and "install latest version of my lib that can work with upstream version that is compatible with specifier" (`foobar[upstream ~= 2.2]`). Because there are multiple versions of upstream in the development at the same time, it's necessary.

Comment: I'm no setuptools expert, but I don't think setuptools is really meant to handle what you're describing.  What you can do with `pip install` is say "install this package and whatever dependencies it needs".  I don't know of a way to say "install the latest version of this package that can work with specific version X of another package".  More generally, I don't think pip or setuptools can track versions at all for non-Python libraries, so I think anything you want to do with specifying the upstream version is stuff you'll have to do yourself.